# Renaming integers within a data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics, regression, forcats

Using `R`...

I have a `data.frame` with five variables.

One of the variables `colr` has values ranging from 1 to 5.

Defined as an `integer` with values   `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, and `5`.

**Problem:** I would like to build a regression model where the values within `colr`, the integers `1`,`2`,`3`,`4`, and `5` are reported as independent variables with the following names.

`1` = Silver, 
`2` = Blue, 
`3` = Pink, 
`4` = Other than Silver, Blue or Pink, 
`5` = Color Not Reported.

**Question:** Is there a way to extract or rename these values in a way that is different from the following (as this process does not rename, eg. `1` to `Silver` in the summary regression output):

```
lm(dependent variable ~ + I(colr.f == 1) + 
                          I(colr.f == 2) + 
                          I(colr.f == 3) + 
                          I(colr.f == 4) + 
                          I(colr.f == 5),
                          data = df)
```

I am open to any method that would allow me to create and name these different values independently but would prefer to see if there is a way to do so using the `tidyverse` or `dplyr` as this is something I have to do frequently when building multivariate models.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: you should use a factor as suggested by Ben T. In the approach you have posted, you have no base level, which will lead to perfect collinearity

Comment: i tried to run the code ben provided but it is telling me this...`Error in factor(colr.f, levels = c(1:5), labels = c("Silver", "Blue",  : 
  object 'colr.f' not found`

Comment: in this case your variable in the dataframe does not have the name `colr.f` i suppose

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I'm understanding your question the right way, but can't you just use

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
 mutate(color=factor(colr.f, levels=c(1:5), labels=c("silver", "blue", "pink", "not s, b, p", "not reported"))
```

and then just run the regression on `color` only.

/edit for clarification. Making up some data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x=rnorm(100),
  color=factor(rep(c(1,2,3,4,5), each=20), 
               labels=c("Silver", "Blue", "Pink", "Not S, B, P", "Not reported")),
  y=rnorm(100, 4))

m1 <- lm(y~x+color, data=df)
m2 <- lm(y~x+color-1, data=df)
summary(m1)
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x + color, data = df)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.96394 -0.59647  0.00237  0.56916  2.13392 

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)        3.93238    0.19312  20.362   <2e-16 ***
x                  0.13588    0.09856   1.379    0.171    
colorBlue         -0.07862    0.27705  -0.284    0.777    
colorPink         -0.02167    0.27393  -0.079    0.937    
colorNot S, B, P   0.15238    0.27221   0.560    0.577    
colorNot reported  0.14139    0.27230   0.519    0.605    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.8606 on 94 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.0268,    Adjusted R-squared:  -0.02496 
F-statistic: 0.5177 on 5 and 94 DF,  p-value: 0.7623

summary(m2)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x + color - 1, data = df)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.96394 -0.59647  0.00237  0.56916  2.13392 

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
x                  0.13588    0.09856   1.379    0.171    
colorSilver        3.93238    0.19312  20.362   <2e-16 ***
colorBlue          3.85376    0.19570  19.692   <2e-16 ***
colorPink          3.91071    0.19301  20.262   <2e-16 ***
colorNot S, B, P   4.08477    0.19375  21.083   <2e-16 ***
colorNot reported  4.07377    0.19256  21.156   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.8606 on 94 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9578,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9551 
F-statistic: 355.5 on 6 and 94 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

The first model is a model with intercept, therefore one of the factor levels must be dropped to avoid perfect multicollinearity. In this case, the "effect" of silver is the value of the intercept, while the "effect" of the other colors is the intercept coefficient value + their respective coefficient value.

The second model is estimated without intercept (without constant), so you can see the individual effects. However, you should probably know what you are doing before estimating the model without intercept.

Comment: thanks ben. maybe this will simplify it. without `mutating` the regression model would be `lm(price ~ colr, data = df) but when i summarize the regression output for these results I would not see each `level`, eg `1` which I would like to rename `silver` broken out independently to see the `silver` colors individual effect on `price`. Does this change anything about your answer? thanks again

Answer (score 3):

If you have this:

```r
df <- data.frame(int = sample(5, 20, TRUE), value = rnorm(20))
df
#>    int       value
#> 1    3 -0.62042198
#> 2    4  0.85009260
#> 3    5 -1.04971518
#> 4    1 -2.58255471
#> 5    1  0.62357772
#> 6    4  0.00286785
#> 7    4 -0.05981318
#> 8    4  0.72961261
#> 9    4 -0.03156315
#> 10   1 -2.05486209
#> 11   5  1.77099554
#> 12   1  1.02790956
#> 13   1 -0.70354012
#> 14   1  0.27353731
#> 15   2 -0.04817215
#> 16   2  0.17151374
#> 17   5 -0.54824346
#> 18   2  0.41123284
#> 19   5  0.05466070
#> 20   1 -0.41029986
```

You can do this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- df %>% mutate(color = factor(c("red", "green", "orange", "blue", "pink"))[int])
df
#>    int       value  color
#> 1    3 -0.62042198 orange
#> 2    4  0.85009260   blue
#> 3    5 -1.04971518   pink
#> 4    1 -2.58255471    red
#> 5    1  0.62357772    red
#> 6    4  0.00286785   blue
#> 7    4 -0.05981318   blue
#> 8    4  0.72961261   blue
#> 9    4 -0.03156315   blue
#> 10   1 -2.05486209    red
#> 11   5  1.77099554   pink
#> 12   1  1.02790956    red
#> 13   1 -0.70354012    red
#> 14   1  0.27353731    red
#> 15   2 -0.04817215  green
#> 16   2  0.17151374  green
#> 17   5 -0.54824346   pink
#> 18   2  0.41123284  green
#> 19   5  0.05466070   pink
#> 20   1 -0.41029986    red
```

Which allows a regression like this:

```r
lm(value ~ color, data = df) %>% summary()
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = value ~ color, data = df)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
#> -2.03595 -0.33687 -0.00447  0.46149  1.71407 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
#> (Intercept)   0.2982     0.4681   0.637    0.534
#> colorgreen   -0.1200     0.7644  -0.157    0.877
#> colororange  -0.9187     1.1466  -0.801    0.436
#> colorpink    -0.2413     0.7021  -0.344    0.736
#> colorred     -0.8448     0.6129  -1.378    0.188
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 1.047 on 15 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.1451, Adjusted R-squared:  -0.0829 
#> F-statistic: 0.6364 on 4 and 15 DF,  p-value: 0.6444
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

With base R.

```
labels <- c("Silver", "Blue", "Pink", "Other Color", "Color Not Reported")

df$colr.f2 <- factor(colr.f, labels = labels, levels = seq_along(labels))
```